# Whether to download a zip of png images and maintain locally (or) download each png image on demand

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Our Xamarin forms app supports both Android and IOS. This app uses a lot of png images on each and every screen.
We are looking for a better approach to deal with it. Whether to download a zip of png images and maintain them locally (or) download each png image on demand and cache it. It's ok if the application takes bit more time at the time of login. Could you please suggest.

Comment: What are the images for? Are they content? Or are they part of how the app should look?

Comment: These are png images representing status of object based on some conditions. The idea to download and maintain them locally.